# Symfony2 APYDataGridbundle ManyToMany

Tags: php, symfony, datagrid, many-to-many

I’m working with Symfony2 and [APYDataGridBundle](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle).
I have a many to many relationship, between Film and Genre objects:

```
/**
* Film
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Film")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Filmoteca\FilmoBundle\Repository\FilmRepository")
* @GRID\Source(columns="id, genres.genre")
*/

class Film
{

/**
 * @var \Filmoteca\FilmoBundle\Entity\Genre
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Genre", inversedBy="films")
 *          @ORM\JoinTable(name="genre_films")
 * 
 * @GRID\Column(field="genres.genre", title="Genre", filter="select", selectMulti="true)
 **/
private $genres;
```

And in my Genres class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Film", mappedBy="genres")
 **/
private $films;
```

It’s working fine, but, for each genre of each film, a different row is showed. I would like to get a column which shows all the genres.

I get:
(row1) 7/ Bande à part/ Drama
(row2) 7/ Bande à part/ Commedy

But I would like to see an array with all the genres:
(row) 7/ Bande à part/ Drama, Comedy

Any ideas? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:
`@GRID\Column(field="genres.genre:GroupConcat", title="Genre", filter="select", selectMulti="true")`
and add a groupBy for the source:
`@GRID\Source(columns="id, genres.genre:GroupConcat", groupBy={"id"})`

If GroupConcat does not work out of the box, you have to add a doctrine extension as described in [APYDataGridBundle DQL function notation documentation](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/columns_configuration/annotations/dql_function.md)

I suggest : https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions